# Project Euler Problem #2 in Swift Sum of Fibonacci Numbers Below 4 Million

Tags: swift

I am very new to coding and am trying to learn Swift by completing Project Euler problems. I seem to have different versions of Swift code that are causing a multitude of errors. If there is any advice you may have on the formatting of my question for future reference please let me know, Thanks.

Below are some examples of things I've looked at.

Example 1

```
    let nextState = { (state: inout T) -> T? in
        // Return `nil` if condition is no longer satisfied:
        guard condition(state) else { return nil }
        // Update current value _after_ returning from this call:
        defer { state = next(state) }
        // Return current value:
        return state
    }
    return sequence(state: first, next: nextState)
}
```

---

Example 2

```
// F[n] = F[n-1] + F[n-2]
// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144
// Find the fibonacci number for n interations
func fibonacci(n: Int) {

    var num1 = 0
    var num2 = 1

    for _ in 0 ..< n {

        let num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = num
    }

    print("result = \(num2)")
}
fibonacci(7)


// Using Recursion
func fibonacciRecursiveNum1(num1: Int, num2: Int, steps: Int) {

    if steps > 0 {
        let newNum = num1 + num2
        fibonacciRecursiveNum1(num2, num2: newNum, steps: steps-1)
    }
    else {
        print("result = \(num2)")
    }
}
fibonacciRecursiveNum1(0, num2: 1, steps: 7)
```

---

Example 3

```
    return SequenceOf { _ -> GeneratorOf<Int> in
        var (a, b) = (1, 0)
        return GeneratorOf {
            (b, a) = (a, b + a)
            if b > max { return nil }
            return b
        }
    }
}


let sum = reduce(fibonacciTo(4_000_000), 0) {a, n in (n % 2 == 0) ? a + n : a }
```

In the examples of people's code I have looked at, I get errors that I think have something to do with incompatible versions of Swift.

Comment: Hi ADGW, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide the errors you're getting? That will help the community answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your examples are outdated. Since Swift 3 the first parameter label is required

```
fibonacci(n: 7)
```

and

```
fibonacciRecursiveNum1(num1: num2, num2: newNum, steps: steps-1)

...

fibonacciRecursiveNum1(num1 : 0, num2: 1, steps: 7)
```

Second of all, the maximum of Fibonacci iterations in an `Int64` value is 91, 92 and above exceeds the 64 bit range and causes a crash.